# Show contact list using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap sample application to list all contacts with their names, but I am unable to do so.

Below is my `onSuccess()` function. I am getting **Found 7 contacts** as a message in second line of this function. I am showing some of the results with my trials in getting the name.

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
    var con = document.getElementById('con');

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
       navigator.notification.alert(contacts[i].name);
    } 
};
```

**Trials :**

```
  <br/>
  1). navigator.notification.alert(contacts[i])<br/>
  Result ->
  {"id":"0","displayName":"Andrew Hill","nickname":"Andrew Hill",
  "phoneNumbers":["(206)5550001"],"emails":["Andy@fai=urthcoffee.com"],
  "addresses":["Microsoft.Phone.UserData.ContactAddress"],
  "urls":["www.fourthcoffee..com"]}
   and like in the same foramt for other 6 contacts.

  2). navigator.notification.alert(contacts[i].name)<br/>
  Result ->
  message 
  like same for all.

  3). navigator.notification.alert(contacts[i].name[i].value)<br/>
  Result ->
  shows nothing.
```

How can I get the name field?

Comment: hi ios / Android ? which phonegap version plz ..

Comment: @ArjunTRaj I am working on Window Phone 7 using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 6):

Well, I have not tested for windows phone 7 but it is working fine with iOS/android, Tested on device and simulator both.

```
navigator.contacts.find(
    ['displayName', 'name','phoneNumbers'],
    function(contacts){
        var contact_name;
        var contact_phone;
        for( i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            if(contacts[i].name.formatted != null && contacts[i].name.formatted != undefined ) {
                contact_name = contacts[i].name.formatted;
                contact_name = contact_name.replace(/'/g,"''");
                if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers != null && contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length > 0 && contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value != null && contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value != undefined ) {
                    console.log( contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value );
                    contact_phone = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value;
                } else {
                    console.log( "--No Number-" );
                    contact_phone = "";
                }
            }
        }
    },function(error){
        alert(error);
    },{ filter:"", multiple:true }
);
```